# How to getWidht from applet class?

Tags: java, applet

for example

first class:

```
class Stuck {

private int i;

public void WhatIwant(){
    i = FirstClass.getWidht();
    }
}
```

main class:

```
public class FirstClass extends applet{

@Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(500, 500);
    }
}
```

I try create new FirstClass but is show 0?
Please help me, i am stuck. I try first in google.

Comment: when ur calling `FirstClass.getWidth()`, the `init()` method hasn't been called yet, so the size is set to `0,0`.

Comment: *"is show 0"*  Rubbish!  The code shown has at least two **compilation errors,** so would not do anything at run-time.  Stop wasting our time by posting 'something like' the code being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I explained in my comment, when you are calling `FirstClass.getWidth()`, the `init()` method of the `Applet` hasn't been called yet. And, more importantly, **you can't access  the *non-static* `getWidth()` method of `FirstClass` like that!**. Make sure you create an object of `FirstClass` to access it like:

```
FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
fc.init(); // Not recommended.
// Now, you can get the width.
```

But this not recommended. Hence you should this approach instead:

```
1. Create a method "getPreferredSize()" in the "FirstClass". Declare and
initialize two private variables namely "width" and "height":

public class FirstClass extends Applet {
    private int width = 400;
    private int height = 300;
    ...
    @Override
    public void Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width,height);
    }
    ...

2. Or you can directly return the preferred width as:

    ...
    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return width;
        // OR:
        // return (int)getPreferredSize().getWidth();
    } //and the same for height
```